# Stats Test with Continuous X and discrete Y

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am comparing income (continuous) with return to work status (discrete variable with three possible values: 1,2,3). What stats test would I use to perform this? I was thinking of breaking income into bins and doing chi square but also remember from stats classes never to break continuous variables into discrete.

I appreciate any help,
Thank You!

Comment: Income is often modelled by gamma distributions. Without knowing more about the data, I think a promising way forward would be to do a gamma regression and use return to work status as a binary indicator.  Then you can do a likelihood ratio test to determine if the return to work variable has any impact on the average income.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! return to work has 3 possible options (returned, returned with modified hours, did not return), how would I change analysis since its not binary?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes salaries are modeled as 'lognormal', which means logarithms of
salaries are normal.  Here are three lognormal samples (for three levels
of work status), each of size 100. These are fake data sampled using R.

```
summary(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.530   4.098  16.130  52.066  43.913 606.520 
[1] 95.07034  # SD x1
summary(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.24   10.57   34.77  167.76   85.47 3566.54 
[1] 493.6368
summary(x3); sd(x3)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.81   12.14   45.22  274.24  221.62 6095.01 
[1] 758.7552
```

Here are boxplots of the three groups of (highly skewed) salaries:

```
x = c(x1,x2,x3);  gp = rep(1:3, each=100)
boxplot(x ~ gp, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Also, boxplots of the three groups of logged salaries, which seem nearly normal.

```
boxplot(log(x) ~ gp, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

In R, the procedure `oneway.test` does a one-way ANOVA on several
groups of data without requiring group variances to be equal.
For my artificial data, there are highly significant differences among
the means of the logged salaries in the three groups.

> For an ordinary ANOVA the denominator degrees of freedom would be 197, if `oneway.test` shows
> that `denom DF` is much lower than that, it's an indication that important adjustments
> have been made to account for unequal group variances; it happens that there is no such indication here.

```
oneway.test(log(x)~gp)

        One-way analysis of means 
        (not assuming equal variances)

data:  log(x) and gp
F = 9.4665, num df = 2.00, denom df = 196.68, p-value = 0.0001188
```

With some protection against 'false discovery' (such as Bonferroni adjustments of P-values to be taken as significant), one can use Welch
2-sample t tests, to see which group means differ.

For my artificial data Groups 1 and 2 differ significantly, but Groups 2 and 3 do not. (In view of the boxplots above of logged salaries, these conclusions are
not surprising.)

```
t.test(log(x1), log(x2))$p.val
[1] 0.007127908
t.test(log(x2), log(x3))$p.val
[1] 0.133039
```

Notes:

(1) I have no objection to the suggestion in @Demetri's comment,
if your salary data are gamma distributed and you are familiar with the method suggested there.

(2) In case you want to try to replicate or
extend my analysis, the R code used to sample my artificial data is
shown below. [Taking exponentials of my suggested normal means/medians
gives approximate medians of my lognormal data, but *not the means* of heavily skewed
lognormal samples. In any of the groups, there may be a very few people with surprisingly high incomes---perhaps not from current or recent employment.]

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = round(exp(rnorm(100, log(20), log(5))), 2)
x2 = round(exp(rnorm(100, log(30), log(6))), 2)
x3 = round(exp(rnorm(100, log(45), log(7))), 2)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! With this method arent you taking return to work as the x variable? I thought income was supposed to be x? Would switching the x and y around like that be ok?

Comment: Following the description in your Question, my three independent samples `x1, x2, x2` of incomes relate to the three different 'return to work' conditions. You could consider them as three different levels of a factor. Return to work is categorical, salary is numerical.

Comment: I got that part but i want income to be the the independent variable and see if that can predict return to work status. Wouldn't this type of analysis be doing the opposite? Thanks!